# How can I get 2 Time Zone from EKEvent? There are two startTimeZone, but not endTimeZone

Tags: timezone, ekevent

I am making a calendar app and want to create a view for each event, instead of using EventKitUI. When I get the data with like;

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
if let val = eventStore.eventWithIdentifier(id) {
  print(val)
}
```

It shows

```
 startTimeZone =    US/Pacific (PST) offset -28800; 
 startTimeZone =    America/New_York (EST) offset -18000 ...
```

When I get timezone data with;

```
print(val.timeZone)
```

It shows only first one. I need to second one too!

```
Optional(US/Pacific (PST) offset -28800)
```

How can I get it? The second timeZone must be for endDate.

Answer (score 3):

I should have tested... I think it is a kind of bug. Anyway, I wrote the answer for the people like me.

```
val.valueForKey("startTimeZone") //you can get first one
val.valueForKey("endTimeZone") //you can get time zone for end.
```